# remount disk with running process

Tags: linux, embedded, mount

I have an embedded application that I am working on. To protect the data on this image its partitions are mounted RO (this helps prevent flash errors when the power is lost unexpectedly since I cannot guarantee clean shutdowns, you could pull the plug)

An application I am working that needs to be protected resides on this RO partition, however this program also needs to be able to change configuration files on the same RO file system. I have code that allows me to remount this partition RW as needed (eg for firmware updates), but this requires all the processes to be stopped that are running from the read only partition (ie killall my_application). Hence it is not possible for my application to remount the partition it needs to modify without first killing itself (I am not sure which one is the chicken and which one is the egg, but you get the gist).

Is there a way to start my application in such a way that the entire binary is kept in RAM and there is no link back to the partition from which it was run so that the unmount reports the partition as busy?

Or alternatively is there a way to safely remount this RO partition without first killing the process running on it?

Comment: How are you doing the remount, exactly? Could you post some code?

Comment: Simply having a process running from the volume should not prevent you from doing a remount between RO and RW, however other things might.  Using a ramdisk might be another solution.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: True, which is why I asked how the remounting is done. If it isn't the equivalent of `mount -oremount,ro`, but rather unmount and mount, it should Just Work™

Comment: You'd need to do the equivalent of remount - but you need to watch out for the location of mtab, daemons which may have writable files open, etc.

Comment: Err, my comment was reversed. `-oremount` should work, not the unmount and mount.

Comment: Great, thank you! "mount -o remount,rw newdir" seems to work, originally I was unmounting the device and remounting it. I am curious why remount works and a umount followed by a mount doesn't (and fails with a "device is busy." error) if the whole binary is already loaded into RAM?

Comment: IIRC, remount just asks the FS driver nicely to change settings. The underlying file system never goes away.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy it to a tmpfs filesystem and execute it from there. A tmpfs filesystem stores all data in RAM and sometimes on your SWAP partition.

Passing the -oremount flag to mount should also work.